# How to call multiple soap calls parallel in java-spring application

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, soap

I want to make my soap request calls parallel in java.
I'm new to multithreading not getting the way to do it.

```
public List<TB600Model.Response> getTableDesc(final List<TB600Model.Request> requests)  
{
    List<TB600Model.Response> responses = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TB600Model.Request request : requests) 
    {
        responses.add(
            this.modifyDescription(
                this.getDescription(
                    request.getSite()
                    ,request.getDescType()
                    ,request.getKeyData()
                    ,request.getEffMdy()
                )
                ,request.getDescType()
                ,request.getKeyData()
            )
        );
    }
    return responses;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNfZQ.png)

Comment: Try to edit your question and send it in the right form, use "code tag" for your code

Comment: @Mehdi updated code any idea how can i make calls run parallely it's impacting performance of my application.

Comment: This code does not send any soap call yet, It just save response information in an array list. put the sending section and I will tell you how to write it in parallel

Comment: the part in the code getDescription is invoking client.

Comment: Added image of the code

Answer (score 1):

For Java 8+ Try to use this method instead :

```
requests.parallelStream().forEach(request -> {...});
```

put the code for **response.add** instead of `...`

For earlier version :

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
List<Response> responses = new ArrayList<>();
for(Request request:  requests){
    Future<Response> future = es.submit(new Callable<Response>() {
        @Override
        public Response call() throws Exception {
           //create your response here and return
        }
    });

    try {
        responses.add(future.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm using 1.7 version and it's not accepting lambda expression for this.

Comment: Next time please mention everything in your questions first. try the above code